# Open source app for mounting, extracting, creating ISOs

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation

I really need a Open source app that can handle:

1. Mounting of ISO
2. Extraction of ISO
3. Creation of ISO from a real CD/DVD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AcetoneISO, it has all those features.

You can easily install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: Or visit the application's link for more information].

Answer (score 2):

for mounting ISO acetoneiso or furius ISO Mount (not sure about the spelling)
the default archiver (may be gnome file-roller) can extract ISO.